# linux: yank to clipboard, cut to primary

Tags: cut-copy-paste, neovim, linux

I'm using neovim. I want to map the `0` register to the system clipboard and the unnamed register to the system primary (mouse middle click). Is it possible? I can map the unnamed register to primary with

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

But how to map the `0` register to the clipboard? (Without remapping all yank operations to yank to `+` register).

Comment: I think 0 register is to store recently deleted/yanked text. As far as I know, Numbered registers cannot be mapped.

Comment: The 0 register store only the yanked, not the deleted text. This is why I wish to have it mapped to the clipboard. In my workflow outside vim, I use the clipboard for "I want to keep this for some time" and the primary selection for "just select and paste somewhere without overwriting the clipboard". So I think it's natural to map the clipboard to the 0 register and the primary selection to the unnamed register.

Comment: I'v found there is `TextYankPost` autocmd in last version (0.1.3) of neovim. Maybe it can help. I'm experimenting with it...